# How to make switch work with enum? C# Unity

Tags: unity, c#

I'm working on a script to fade UI elements in Unity, similar to a selector, where you can select the type of fading, and duration, and image to fade

[image]

I found that enum is the best option to achieve that result, but I have a problem, when I run the code only element of the enum work and the other don't, no matter if I use switchor if just the first statement run, I don't know what's wrong with the code

- Please explain your answer
- Please explain why the code is wrong
- Please give feedback on how to improve

I'm using Unity version 5.3.5f1 and Visual Studio Community 2015

**Goal**

- Make the enum work properly using either switch or if
- Be able to use the variables inside the FadeOperations class to make
  the calculations inside the Test class
- Select from an array the type of desired operation
- Select an UI element from Heriarchy and fade it

**Steps**

- Create new Unity project (2D or 3D)
- Create UI Image
- Create Empty game object
- Create new C# script (I called it Test)
- Attach new script to empty game object

**Code**

Here's my code so far...

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

 public enum FadeManager
 {
     fadeIn,
     fadeOut
 };

 [System.Serializable]
 public class FadeOperations
 {
     [Tooltip("Type of fading")]
     public FadeManager fadeType;

     [Tooltip("Duration time of the fading")]
     public float duration;

     [Tooltip("Select the image to fade")]
     public Image fadeImage;
 }

 public class Test : MonoBehaviour
 {
     [Tooltip("Select your type of fade")]
     public FadeOperations[] fadeOperations;

     //Reference to the class FadeOperations
     private FadeOperations _fo = new FadeOperations();

     //Loop for debug
     private void Update()
     {
         switch (_fo.fadeType)
         {
             Debug.Log(_fo.fadeType)
             //This statement works
             case FadeManager.fadeIn:
                 Debug.Log("Fadein"); //Only this piece of code works
                 break;

             //This statement doesn't work
             case FadeManager.fadeOut:
                 Debug.Log("Fadeout");
                 break;
         }
      }
  }
```

The result of the Log (_fo.fadeType) before the switch

```
fadeIn
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Test:Start() (at Assets/_Scripts/Test.cs:34)
```

Comment: Your code looks okay. Just before your `switch` statement, could you add `Debug.Log(_fo.fadeType);` to see which FadeManager it's using? Wouldn't surprise me if it's not changing as you expect.

Comment: I changed `Update()` for `Start()` and got this Log `fadeIn
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Test:Start() (at Assets/_Scripts/Test.cs:34)`

Comment: When you say "only one enum statement work," do you mean you always get the `fadeIn` behaviour, no matter how you configure your Inspector parameters in the `FadeOperations` array? If so, it could be because your code as written *never references* this array. It only looks at the value of the private member `_fo` which is initialised to a new default `FadeOperations` struct when your `Test` class is instantiated and never modified, so `_fo.fadeType` will always be the default (first) value, `fadeIn`. If this describes your problem, I can elaborate on this and suggest fixes in an answer.

Comment: Exactly as you said, only the first value of the enum is showing, and would you please elaborate more??

Answer (score 2):

Your switch statement is checking `_fo.fadeType`. Because `_fo` is private without `[SerializeField]`, it won't show up in Unity's Inspector tab unless you enable Debug mode.

Your code has `_fo = new FadeOperations();` which creates a new `FadeOperations`, and the `fadeType` is `FadeManager.fadeIn` by default since it's first in the enum, and that's what's being cased every time.

If you write it as:

```
[SerializeField] private FadeOperations _fo = new FadeOperations();
```

^ this will show the `_fo` variable in the Inspector, and you can see the value, as this is what your switch statement is checking against.

Based on your `public FadeOperations[] fadeOperations;` line, I assume you've added at least one FadeOperation via the Inspector to this array. Perhaps you'd instead want to make your switch statement check the first item in the array:

```
switch (fadeOperations[0].fadeType) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tested it and got an error in the `switch` `A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type` the `[SerializeField]` duplicate the variable I am already using in the inspector, and also I edited my question, maybe with more details I can explain better
`

Comment: Ah. I've updated my answer for the end switch statement: `switch (fadeOperations[0].fadeType) {`

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of an `enum` being used in a `switch` statement. I hope that this helps you.

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections; 

public class MyScriptFile : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Define possible states for enemy using an enum 
    public enum EnemyState {CHASE, FLEE, FIGHT, HIDE}; 

    // The current state of enemy
    public EnemyState ActiveState = EnemyState.CHASE; 

    // Update is called once per frame 
    void Update ()
    {
        // Check the ActiveState variable 
        switch(ActiveState) 
        { 
            // Check one case
            case EnemyState.FIGHT: 
                {
                    //Perform fight code here
                    Debug.Log ("Entered fight state"); 
                }
                break; 

            // Check multiple cases at once
            case EnemyState.FLEE: 
            case EnemyState.HIDE: 
            { 
                //Flee and hide performs the same behaviour 
                Debug.Log ("Entered flee or hide state"); 
            } 
            break;

            // Default case when all other states fail 
            default: 
            {
                //This is used for the chase state 
                Debug.Log ("Entered chase state");
            } 
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already discussed, your use of enums in a switch statement is actually correct. Your problem is that your checking against a private variable that you only initialise, rather than the public variables that *might* offer differant values. As a result, the switch statement will *always* trigger the `case:FadeManager.fadeIn` case, because a `FadeManager` variable that has been *initialised*, and *only* initialised, will only ever report the default value.

### Enums in Switch Statements

As mentioned, your code is correct. Using enums as follows will work correctly, providing you check the correct variable. For the purpose of extending your understanding, I will also mention the `int` option; while it will likely always be redundant to do so, you could also check against integer values. The integer would need to correspond with a valid index number in your enum, and would still need to be cast as a type of your enum.

```
public enum FadeManager
{
    fadeIn, // index 0
    fadeOut // index 1
};

switch(fadeOperation.fadeType)
{
    case (FadeManager)0:
    case (FadeManager.fadeIn):
        Debug.Log("Fadein"); //Only this piece of code works
        break;

    case (FadeManager)1:
    case (FadeManager.fadeOut):
        Debug.Log("Fadeout");
        break;

    default:
}
```

As a small caveat, I will make two more points. Firstly, some will argue that you should *always* have a `default:` case to handle any case that does not fall within the above. In cases like this, you can pretty much guarantee that will not happen, so it is more a matter of style. Secondly, in some cases, you can "fall through" cases. For example, if you wanted to run the code in "fadeOut" for "fadeIn" aswell, you could remove the `break;` from "fadeIn" and have your code "fall through" into the next statement. ***You can not do that in C#***, or at least, not in Unity. That said, I feel it might be useful to know that you can do so in other contexts.

### Your Errors

Your primary error actually comes from your understanding of what your doing, and how it should react. The switch, itself, is pretty much solid. That said, there *is* an error in your switch; your `Debug.Log()` statement. I believe you have added this by suggestion, and no one has pointed out the error in your implementation.

#### Checking against a private `FadeManager`:

Your logic error falls to the instance of `FadeManager` your trying to check against. In your code, you have a reference to a `FadeManager` array, and a single `FadeManager` inside a `FadeOperations` class. While your array is `public`, your single reference is inside a `private` class reference. Given that this is the only code you have, we can infer that this `private FadeManager _fo` is never changed; being `private` also means you can not change it directly from the inspector.

As a result, you set up your reference as a default value. Since this value has no means to change, it will *always* trigger `case:FadeManager.fadeIn`.

To further test this, simply change `private FadeOperations _fo` to `public FadeOperations _fo`. You should not need to include the `= new FadeOperations()` constructor. While my knowledge on constructor precedence is not perfect, I have confirmed that setting `_fo` to `public` and changing its values in the inspector, the values persist when I play-test.

You can see your code correctly prints its `Debug.Log()` statements, below, where I have simply converted `_fo` to `public`.

[image: The debug log correctly responds to changes in _fo.fadeType.]

### Code inside a `switch` statement must also be inside a `case`

As your code stands, it throws many errors, due to the `Debug.Log()` statement you have added to the inside of your `switch` statement. ***all code*** must correspond to a specific `case`, and as such, many errors will pop up from misinterpretation of the initial `Debug.Log()`. You should place `Debug.Log(_fo.fadeType)` outside of the `switch` statement, or at least enclose it inside a specific `case`.

This appears to be a line added at a later date than your original question, but regardless, it is important to understand that as it is this line will prevent your code from compiling.

Answer (score -2):

public enum JumpState { NormalJump, LongJump};
public JumpState jumpValue;
and you can change the value like
jumpValue = JumpState.NormalJump;

Comment: How does this add to the already proposed answers?